# How to query report descriptions in SSRS

Tags: t-sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

How do you query (TSQL) report descriptions in SSRS 2008 R2? I have tried checking the tables under the ReportServer database, but I am not finding them there. The report description seems like something you would be able to query.[image: I want to query the description column.]

Comment: This might be helpful, try this script and play around you might find a description column for the report. https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/42440a6b-c5b1-4acc-9632-d608d1c40a5c

Comment: I also like this one: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/dbtechresource/2015/04/04/retrieve-ssrs-report-server-database-information/

Comment: But you really shouldn't rely on queries written against the ssrs db. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/60dd3392-42d8-4dc4-b8e6-15e9aeaad29e/table-explaination-for-dbocatalog-table-in-reportserver-database?forum=sqlreportingservices

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `Description` column in the `Catalog` table:

```
SELECT Path, Name, Description FROM ReportServer.dbo.Catalog
```